# Listview with Checkbox is checking more than one checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

So I've been working on a app with a listview with checkbox's and I've noticed when I select a item say the first item on the list when I scroll down the first item after scrolling down a full page has the checkbox selected as well.  I have a feeling this is due to recyled views but I'm curious as to the solution for this.  I had tried adding a viewholder but this didn't fix the issue.  Just wondering what I'm missing.  Code for the getview on the adapter is below:

```
        public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Android.Views.View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GroupTimeTrackerTemplate, parent, false);
            }
            tblWorkers item = this[position];

            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.UserNameTextView).Text = this[position].nWorkerFirstname + " " + this[position].nWorkerLastname;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.StatusTextView).Text = this[position].nStatusShort;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.UserRoleTextView).Text = this[position].nTitle;
            CheckBox chkSelect = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.ChkSelect);
            chkSelect.Tag = item.nWorkerFirstname + " " + item.nWorkerLastname;

            chkSelect.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            chkSelect.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(this.context));
            return view;
        }

        private class CheckChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
        {

            private Activity activity;

            public CheckChangeListener(Activity activity)
            {
                this.activity = activity;
            }

            public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    string name = (string)buttonView.Tag;
                    string text = string.Format("{0} Checked.", name);
                    Toast.MakeText(this.activity, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that has a View Holder that works with my dynamic model data.  And this worked for me below is the solution!  The three main points are the business logic object having a bool to hold the item being checked and the view holder helping with performance, and lastly because of the recyling of the views you cannot reliably use the list[position] in the click event so I used a wrapper!

View Holder :

```
    private class MyViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtStatus;
        public TextView txtTitle;
        public CheckBox chkItem;

    }
```

Adapter GetView :

```
    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        var item = list[position];
        Android.Views.View view = convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GroupTimeTrackerTemplate, null);
            holder.chkItem = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.ChkSelect);
            holder.txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.UserNameTextView);
            holder.txtStatus = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.StatusTextView);
            holder.txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.UserRoleTextView);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;

        }
        holder.chkItem.Checked = item.StatusSelected;
        if (holder.chkItem.Checked)
        {
            holder.chkItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            holder.chkItem.Enabled = true;
        }
        holder.chkItem.Tag = new MyWrapper<int>(position);
        holder.txtName.Text = item.nWorkerFirstname + " " + item.nWorkerLastname;
        holder.txtStatus.Text = item.nStatusShort;
        holder.txtTitle.Text = item.nTitle;
        holder.chkItem.Click -= HolderChkItemClick;
        holder.chkItem.Click += HolderChkItemClick;
        if (statoChk[position] == 0)
        {
            holder.chkItem.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            holder.chkItem.Checked = true;
        }


        return view;
    }
```

Click Event for checkbox, Wrapper, and array :

```
    tblWorkers OrigSel = null;
    void HolderChkItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var chk = sender as CheckBox;
        int pos = ((MyWrapper<int>)chk.Tag).value;
        tblWorkers selectedWorker = list[pos];
        if (Vm.SelectedWorker == null)
        {
            OrigSel = selectedWorker;
            IntentManager.Instance.OriginalSelectedWorker = OrigSel;
            Vm.GroupTimeTrackerStatusType = OrigSel.nStatusShort;
        }
        Vm.SelectedWorker = selectedWorker;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            if (selectedWorker.nStatusShort == OrigSel.nStatusShort)
            {
                statoChk[pos] = 1;
                Vm.GroupTimeList.Add(selectedWorker);
            }
            else
            {
                statoChk[pos] = 0;
                chk.Checked = false;
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Please Select Workers with the Same Time Status. Current Status : " + OrigSel.nStatusShort, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            statoChk[pos] = 0;
            Vm.GroupTimeList.Remove(selectedWorker);
            if (Vm.GroupTimeList.Count == 0)
            {
                Vm.SelectedWorker = null;
                OrigSel = null;
                IntentManager.Instance.OriginalSelectedWorker = null;
                Vm.GroupTimeTrackerStatusType = "";
            }
        }


    }

    public class MyWrapper<T> : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        private T _value;
        public MyWrapper(T managedValue)
        {
            _value = managedValue;
        }
        public T value { get { return _value; } }
    }


    int[] statoChk;
    public int[] StatoCheck
    {
        get { return statoChk; }
        set { statoChk = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't personally have developed Android through Xamarin I have the Android knowledge to get you in the right direction.

As you correctly stated the rows in a ListView are recycled. The problem is that, when you are scrolling, the OnCheckedChange method is called and since its recycling the rows it passes in the position of the new row that its not selected, but since it has the same index as the one that was previously selected it changes its value.

For example if you check the box with index 5 and then scroll down, a new row becomes row with index 5 and so it changes its state.

This is a common problem on Android. To solve it, first you need a data structure to keep track of which rows are already checked by storing it in a map or a list.

Then in your GetView make sure that you set the checkbox state to the contents of that position.

Comment: I've done Java and C# they are very similar  Not a whole lot of examples on Xamarin like with Android though.  What is perplexing is that I'm using the actual list I pass in which is the ObervableCollection so position shouldn't be a issue but I guess it is.  Could you give an example in Java?

Answer (score 0):

@Ivan Alburquerque is right, is due to the fact that Android recycles the views in the list.You should always set the value of the checkbox on the GetView method based on the position of your datasource.
In order to avoid all this repetitive code that you are writing here I will suggest you to use a MVVM framework like MvvmCross (https://github.com/mvvmcross/mvvmcross) that does everything for you and the code that you will need to write will be a lot less.
Have fun.

Comment: Then why are you manually setting the values but not just binding to a source and then binding the state of the CheckBox to the value in your ViewModel?

Comment: I am binding to the source but the custom nature of the business logic mandates that I'm having to manually do this.

Comment: Sorry but on your Adapter I don not see anything special. I think that MvvmCross offers a lot of more flexibility and I'm completely used to it that I never write adapters even with a lot of complex data to bind.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  #1 I'm using mvvm light.  #2 my data is highly dynamic and I've removed those portions in the adapter.

Comment: I understand what are u using. Using a Mvvm framework usually means direct binding of data withoud the need of adapter. But if I check you problem again by just assignign the value if the checkbox is checked or not everey type you return a view should solve you problem. Check aome binsings on mvvmcross and u will see ehat I mean for direct binding even with a complex data with multiple different layouts.

Comment: I know what you mean by the binding.  Mvvm Light has the same I use it on other listviews.  But this one has some things I need to do with the data so I used a custom adapter.